# Can't start mysqld on centOS5 after attempting to upgrade to PHP 5.3

Tags: mysql, centos, centos5

I tried to upgrade my system PHP from PHP 5.2 to 5.3 using starting with script http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic.sh.

I then used yum to update it. Everything seemed to work sweet but then I can't start the mysql daemon again, and the new version of PHP doesn't even seem to be in use by the sites.

I have a DV hosted at mediatemple and I just really need to get it going. My next step is to reset the container to factory settings and try and copy everything across.

When I try and start mysql using `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart` I get the following in the error log

```
111020 20:13:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
nohup: cannot run command `/usr/libexec/mysqld': Permission denied
111020 20:13:57 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I hunted all over Google and I can't fine anything with my issue of the lib exec having permission denied.

Using `uname -a` I get the following for my OS info

```
Linux leereichardt.co.nz 2.6.9-023stab051.3-enterprise #1 SMP Wed Nov 4 19:28:06 MSK 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

and `cat /etc/redhat-release` gives me

```
CentOS release 5.2 (Final)
```

Here is my my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
query-cache-type = 1
query-cache-size = 8M

#basedir=/usr
#set-variable=local-infile
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

user=mysql

# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

#set-variable = innodb_buffer_pool_size=2M
#set-variable = innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
#set-variable = innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
#set-variable = innodb_thread_concurrency=2
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid


#set-variable = innodb_buffer_pool_size=2M
#set-variable = innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
#set-variable = innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
#set-variable = innodb_thread_concurrency=2
```

Outputs below
`ls -la /var/lib/mysql`

```
total 28852
drwxr-xr-x 20 mysql mysql     4096 Oct 20 11:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root  root      4096 Oct 20 12:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql    12288 Sep  6 20:12 c5_growtheseed
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Jan 20  2011 cueit
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Apr 20  2010 horde
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mysql mysql  5242880 Oct 20 11:59 ib_logfile0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mysql mysql  5242880 Oct 19 01:59 ib_logfile1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mysql mysql 18874368 Oct 20 11:59 ibdata1
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Apr  9  2010 ifight
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Apr 19  2011 jkb
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Apr  7  2011 joe_amos
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 May 13 19:02 kidontherock
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mysql mysql     2216 Oct 20 11:48 leereichardt.co.nz.err
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Jun  7 20:49 my_wordpress
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Oct 20 12:20 mysql
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql    20480 Apr 13  2010 pathways_moodle
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql    24576 Dec 20  2010 pathways_test_moodle
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Apr  9  2010 phpmyadmin_aUPVzrrE9aev
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     8192 Apr  9  2010 psa
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Mar  1  2011 rscc_website
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Jul 20  2010 rscc_youth
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Jul 14 15:24 spence
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Sep 29 22:28 victor_wp
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Apr 12  2010 wp_theblower
```

Output of `ls -la /var/run/mysqld`

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root mysql 4096 Oct 20 16:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root  4096 Oct 20 13:21 ..
```

Output of `ls -ld /tmp`

```
drwxrwxrwt 533 root root 16384 Oct 20 13:21 /tmp
```

Comment: Post the MySQL config? Did you run the init script as `root`? `getenforce`? `ls -la /var/lib/mysql`? `ls -la /var/run/mysqld`? `ls -ld /tmp`?

Comment: I added my `my.cnf` file above. I ran the /etc/init.d/msqld script as the su user. Is that what you mean? What are you want me to with these `ls -la /var/lib/mysql`? `ls -la /var/run/mysqld`? `ls -ld /tmp`? Sorry, I'm not all that experienced at linux, and this is something I shouldn't have taken on!

Comment: Run that commands from your terminal and give us the output.

Comment: Added outputs above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that `/usr/libexec/mysqld` is a directory - and directories can not be executed.  It is usually a file.

You need to replace this with the file from the old package.  If that doesn't work, you probably need to reinstall your MySQL-packages.

Comment: I try the /etc/init.d/mysqld when I am logged in as su. Is that what you mean? I tried your answer above and I am getting the same thing.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -la /usr/libexec/mysqld` ?

Comment: `[root@leereichardt httpdocs]# ls -la /usr/libexec/mysqld`
`total 8`
`drwxrwxr-x  2 mysql mysql 4096 Oct 20 12:04 .`
`drwxr-xr-x 10 root  root  4096 Oct 20 12:04 ..`

Sorry. I wasn't sure how to format it properly in the comments

Comment: Edited my reply - it is pretty clear what the problem is now :)

Comment: Any idea on where I can find the executable from the old package? or should I just reinstall?

Comment: HALLELUJAH! It works! I used yum install mysql-server. I'm sure I done it a few times. But this time it actually worked! Thanks for all your help anyway. This has been killing me! Note to self - never do this again!

Answer (score 0):

```
# chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld/
```

and try again.

Comment: Yep. I have seen that one a few times. I tried it but it didn't work. I still get the permission denied error on /usr/libexec/mysqld